# Use Capybara to click link in Bootstrap split-button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, capybara

Using Capybara (latest, 2.4.X), how can I click the link **'Last 100 Closed Accounts'** in the below Bootstrap (latest 3.2) split button? Ignore `ng-click` as it is an AngularJS directive.

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button ng-click="recent(50)"  class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh
</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a ng-click="recent(200)" >Last 200 Opened Accounts</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="recent(300)" >Last 300 Opened Accounts</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a ng-click="closed(100)" >Last 100 Closed Accounts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hair pulling, I finally figured out how to get Capybara to select the last list option in a split button. First, I added `id="refresh_list"` to to the toggle button. I also added an ID for the target list `id="last_100_closed_accounts"`. The following in sequence did the trick (note the `a` prefix to the id), which is really two steps:

```
click_button "refresh_list"
find("a#last_100_closed_accounts").click
```

---

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button ng-click="recent(50)"  class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh
</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="refresh_list">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a ng-click="recent(200)" >Last 200 Opened Accounts</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="recent(300)" >Last 300 Opened Accounts</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a id="last_100_closed_accounts" ng-click="closed(100)" >Last 100 Closed Accounts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Cheers! Hopefully this answer will save others from loosing their hair :-)

Comment: if you don't like adding the id just for testing purposes you can also use something like: `all('.dropdown-menu a').last.click`, assuming you only have 1 drop down menu on the page.

Answer (score -1):

I assigned a class to the links, then was able to:

```
all('.change_account_links').last.click
```

You can't use capybara's find as it will give you an ambiguous match error.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Your response inspired me to go back and try a few options. I finally got it work... posting solution now.